# Function using CLGeocoder() to get convert address to coordinates is not returning coordinates properly

Tags: swift, xcode

Below are the structs I'm using to create Locations for each Truck.

### Truck

```
struct Truck {
    var name: String
    var imageOfTruck: String
    var cuisineType: String
    var customerRatings: [Int]
    var customerRatingAve: Int
    var menu: [MenuItem]
    var currentLocation: Location
}
```

### Location

```
struct Location {

    var location: String
    var coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        
        let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
        var tempCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 0)
        
        geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(location) { (placemarks, error) in
        guard
            let placemarks = placemarks,
            let location = placemarks.first?.location
            
        else {
            print("location not found!")
            return
        }
            
        // Use your location
        let latitude = location.coordinate.latitude
        let longitude = location.coordinate.longitude
            print("latitude: \(latitude)")
            print("longitude: \(longitude)")
            tempCoordinates.latitude = latitude
            tempCoordinates.longitude = longitude

        }
        return tempCoordinates
    }
    
    var departureTime: String
    var nextLocation: NextLocation
}

let truckOne = Truck(name: "truck one",
                     imageOfTruck: "image of truck one",
                     cuisineType: "mexican",
                     customerRatings: [4,4,4],
                     customerRatingAve: 4,
                     menu: [MenuItem(itemName: "taco",
                     itemDescription: "spicy tacos",
                     itemPhotos: ["image one", "image two"],
                     customerRatings: [4,4,4],
                     customerRatingAvg: 4)],
                     currentLocation: Location(location: "physical address goes here (removed for stack overflow)",
                                               departureTime: "5PM",
                                               nextLocation: NextLocation(location: "321 address street",
                                                                          arrivalTime: Date(),
                                                                          departureTime: Date())))

let truckTwo = Truck(name: "truck two",
                     imageOfTruck: "image of truck two",
                     cuisineType: "pizza",
                     customerRatings: [4,4,4],
                     customerRatingAve: 4,
                     menu: [MenuItem(itemName: "pepperoni pizza",
                                     itemDescription: "delicious pepperoni",
                                     itemPhotos: ["image one", "image two"],
                                     customerRatings: [4,4,4],
                                     customerRatingAvg: 4)],
                     currentLocation: Location(location: "physical address goes here (removed for stack overflow)",
                                               departureTime: "4PM",
                                               nextLocation: NextLocation(location: "333 cool st",
                                                                          arrivalTime: Date(),
                                                                          departureTime: Date())))

let arrayOfTrucks = [truckOne, truckTwo]
```

Below is the function where I need to pull the latitude and longitude into.

```
    func convertAddressToCoordinates() {
                
        for trucks in arrayOfTrucks {
            print("truck name: \(trucks.name) truck coordinates: \(trucks.currentLocation.coordinates)")
        }
    }
```

The function prints

> *truck name: truck one truck coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)*

> *truck name: truck two truck coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)*

However, in the computer property `coordinates`, the latitude and longitude are setting themselves properly. From the print statements in the `coordinates` variable, the following prints

> *latitude: 30.2968677*

> *longitude: -81.6114142*

> *latitude: 30.1535125*

> *longitude: -81.6429059*

Is the computed property returning the `tempCoordinates` before it actually gets the `latitude` and `longitude`? If so, what is a workaround for this?

Comment: `geocodeAddressString` runs asynchronously, which means the closure is called later. So it’s not going to work for a computed property. You’ll probably want to write a function with your own completion handler closure.

Answer (score 0):

You ca write your struct like this with completion handler

```
struct Location {
    
    var location: String
    func getLocation(completion: @escaping (CLLocationCoordinate2D?)-> Void) {
        let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
        
        
        geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(location) { (placemarks, error) in
            
            guard
                let placemarks = placemarks,
                let location = placemarks.first?.location?.coordinate
                
                else {
                    print("location not found!")
                    completion(nil)
                    return
            }
            
            completion(location)
            
        }
        
    }
}
```